# ClassNotFoundException using Saxon-HE in C#

Tags: c#, exception, saxon

I've encountered a problem while using the .NET version of Saxon-HE. We've got a .NET Core project which references Saxon-HE 9.7.0.7. If I try to run the following code:

```
private static readonly Processor Processor = new Processor();
```

It gives me a `ClassNotFoundException` for `cli.System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

This is the full error message:

> ClassNotFoundException: cli.System.Xml.XmlDocument    at
>   IKVM.NativeCode.ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader.LoadClass(Object
>   classLoader, Assembly assembly, String name)

Even if I make a blanco ConsoleApplication targeting .NET 4.6.1 and reference Saxon in that project it gives me the `ClassNotFoundException`.

I've tried cleaning the package cache, I've tried reinstalling Java.

Did someone else encounter this problem? Is it a known issue? What can I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note that Saxonica has not tested the .NET version of Saxon under .NET Core, we don't know whether or not it works, and we can't guarantee support. The NuGet package for Saxon-HE was produced by a third party (Max Toro?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the bad news is that Jeroen Frijters, the lead developer of IKVMC, tells us that .NET Core is not currently supported as a target platform by IKVMC, and that supporting it is a lot of work and won't happen any time soon. Saxon on .NET is totally dependent on IKVMC, and is therefore not supported on this platform.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer, we'll try to find another way to use Saxonica.

Comment: hi @koelkastfilosoof, did you find the way to use Saxonica inside .Net Core?

Comment: @ANKIT We are now using the out of the box .NET Core XSLT processors. This did require us to downgrade to XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have been using the `SaxonHE9-7-0-7N-setup.exe` installer or the NuGet package. I prefer the latter.

As stated in the [doc](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!about/installationdotnet), the `saxon9he-api` reference in your project needs the Saxon library (`saxon9he.dll`), the IKVM cross-compiler (`IKVM.Runtime.dll`) and the cross compiled Java OpenJDK class library (`IKVM.OpenJDK.*.dll`). You are probably missing some of these dependencies.

`IKVM.NativeCode.ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader` is in `IKVM.Runtime.dll`.